# Firestore with vuejs

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have successfully setup firebase in my project to use realtime database and it works fine.

When I switched to firebase firestore I get this error in my console :

```
firebase_firestore.js?v=bf36d3e7:13750 Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name (at firebase_firestore.js?v=bf36d3e7:13750:9)
```

**my code :**

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'

export class FireBaseAuth {
  private firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN,
    projectId: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_PROJECTID,
    storageBucket: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  }

  constructor() {
    initializeApp(this.firebaseConfig)
    const fire = getFirestore()
  }
}
```

Am I missing someting? Is there any specific configuration to use firestore?

*Thanks in advance*